# TYPO3 Extension not visible on secondary language

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a website which uses a TYPO3 extension called "Headerslider". This extension works flawlessly on my default language settings on the Front-End (German) for my site. But if I change the sitelanguage on the Front-End to "English", the extension is not visible anymore. I've changed the images for the English site and configured it like it was on the German one, but it's still not visible. The initial installation of the extension contained following steps:

- Choose from which source your jQuery comes from (I chose Google as host)
- Create a marker in Templatesetup
- Insert Marker in HTML - Template

This steps should also work for the English version of my Website, because the German and English version share the same template, aren't they?

Comment: What is the exact extension key? May we can have a look at them in repository.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the extension files and database table if this extension supports multilanguage (it needs db fields like "l10n_parent, sys_language_uid,.." and so on).

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if it's still relevant or not, but I faced the same problem.
(All my carelessness) check the visibility of the block for a specific language